# Nginx in docker throws 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, nginx-location

I am trying to run a service called Grafana behind Nginx webserver,where both services are being run in a docker-compose file.
**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports: ['443:443',"80:80"]
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./etc/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - /home/ec2-user/certs:/etc/ssl

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    restart: always
    ports: ["3000:3000"]
```

**nginx.conf:**

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

    http {
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.pem;
        server {
            listen 443 ssl;
            server_tokens off;
            location /grafana/ {
                rewrite /grafana/(.*) /$1  break;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_bind $server_addr;
            }
        }

    }
```

The grafana service is running on port 3000.
My goal is to access this nginx server from outside, (lets assume its public ip address is: 1.1.1.1) on the address https://1.1.1.1/grafana. With the current configuration i get **502 Bad Gateway** and the error on nginx side:

```
 (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: <<my-public-ip-here>>,
```

Comment: You need to proxy pass to http://grafana:3000 in nging.conf. Apparently, you need to get a clearer picture of the network stack in a docker environment. Try to experiment with networking debugging tools (host, ping, etc.) in two shel docker containers running an interactive shell.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After setting the proxy pass to grafana:3000 i get a 404 not found and a redirect to https://<ip-address>/login on the browser url. On the nginx logs: "/etc/nginx/html/login" failed (2: No such file or directory). Regarding the networking tools, when using curl via cli and trying to reach the url from outside, i get the 301 Moved Permanently, which totally confused me right now. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you try to add this line  `proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000/;` instead of                 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;

Comment: @lakshmikandan thanks for trying to help, setting the proxy_class to 0.0.0.0 throws the same exception as 127.0.0.1, 502 Bad Gateway. Somehow i think im in the wrong direction.

Answer (score -1):

Your containers are running on two separate IP addresses in the docker network, usually `172.17..` by default.

By using a proxy pass like this in the nginx container:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

You are essentially telling it to look for a process on port 3000 *local* to itself, because of the `127.0.0.1` right?

You need to point it in the direction of the Grafana container, try doing:

```
docker inspect <grafana ID> | grep IPAddress
```

Then set the proxy pass to that IP:

```
proxy_pass http://172.0.0.?:3000/
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not help too. I have set the ip of the grafana host, then reloaded nginx container, still the same result.

Comment: Hmm, its strange that the error is refusing you connection - try a docker exec into the nginx container and see if you can curl grafana from there?

Answer (score -1):

I've solved the same issue using something like @james suggested:

```
docker inspect <your inaccessible container is> | grep Gateway
```

Then use this IP address:

```
proxy_pass http://172.xx.0.1:3000/
```

Comment: Sorry, my answer above is not correct, just seen a 504 Gateway timeout... a minute after